# Undefined array key 1, ErrorException while trying to pass a variable to view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

sorry for bothering, I was expected to get some results after passing $wordsset to the view with compact. Similar things work in other parts of the project. But here it doesn't

I would be very pleased to hear from you if you have any idea?

in the function

```
$wordsset = [[1],[[["1"],["1"],["scaun"]]],[[["2"],["1"],["stuhl"]]],[[["3"],["1"],["chair"]],[["4"],["2"],["seat"]]],[[["5"],["la"],["chaise"]]]];

return view('back.editword', compact('wordsset'));
```

in the blade php

```
{{var_export($wordsset,true)}}
```

Comment: Seems like you are calling a key, that doesn't exist on this array. The array  has no error  https://rextester.com/ANRLE43963 you can try with pass second argument false `var_export($wordsset,false)`

Comment: Just dont use second parameter `true` in var_export.